# Using grep with sed and writing a new file based on the results

Tags: sed, grep, xargs

I'm very new to some of the command line utilities and have been looking for a while for a command that would accomplish my goal.

The goal is to find files that contain a string of text, replace it with a new string, and then write the results to a file that is named the same as the original, but in a different directory.

Obviously this is not working, so I am asking how you who know about this stuff would go about it.

```
grep -rl 'stringToFind' *.* | sed 's|oldString|newString|g' < fileNameFromGrep > ./new/fileNameFromGrep
```

Thanks for your input!
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in "`find /YOUR/SEARCH/DIR/ROOT -type f -exec fgrep -l 'stirngToFind' \{\} \;`" ; do
    sed 's|oldString|newString|g' < "${f} > ./new/"${f}
done
```

Will do it for you.

If you have spaces in filenames:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=''
find /PATH -print0 -type f | while read -r -d $'' file
do
    fgrep -l 'stirngToFind' "$file" && \
        sed 's|oldString|newString|g' < "${file} > ./new/"${file}
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: This breaks with files that have spaces

Comment: I do hate spaces in filenames, but you are right @SiegeX. I had updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, your first solution worked, but your second one produced errors:  /center.php
bash: ./center.php > ./new3/./center.php: No such file or directory

Comment: Might I suggest `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do fgrep ... && sed ...; done < <(find /path -type f -print0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
  if grep -qF 'stringToFind' "$file"; then
    sed 's/oldString/newString/g' "$file" > "./new/$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: @Jaypal Fastest finger in the west. *blows on finger* =)

Comment: I am the `fattest finger` in the great white north. Moving to Tampa soon!! ;)

Comment: @Foaminator It also doesn't break with files that have spaces in their name which is not the case with the one you accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in path/to/dir/*
do
   grep -q 'pattern' "$file" > /dev/null
   if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   sed 's/oldString/newString/g' "$file" > /path/to/newdir/"$file"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution found only one of the files.

Comment: @Foaminator Do you have files under sub-directories as well? If that's the case you will have to enable globstar if you have bash 4 to do recursive search

Comment: @Foaminator there was a mistake in the variable I had created variable called files and was using file.

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
sed -ie "s/oldString/newString/g" \
$(grep -Rsi 'pattern' path/to/dir/ | cut -d: -f1)
```

### sed:

- **i** in_place
- **e** exec other command or script

### grep:

- **R** recursive
- **s** Suppress error messages
- **i** ignore case sensitive